# Angular Jasmine Testing - Should I test model constructor Object.assign(this, values)?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have multiple models that use the pattern below in the constructor.

The Angular test coverage recommends that I test my constructors, but should I?

Thanks, in advance.

```js
import { CafeLocation } from "./cafe-location.model";
import { TasteRating } from "./taste-rating.model";
import { ICoffee } from "./coffee.interface";

export class Coffee implements ICoffee {
  public name: string;
  public cafe: string;
  public type: string;
  public cafeLocation: CafeLocation;
  public rating: number;
  public tasteRating: TasteRating;
  public notes?: string;

  constructor(values?: ICoffee) {
    Object.assign(this, values);
  }
}
```

Comment: From another side, do you have any instance methods? Maybe interface is enough if not

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering.

Yes, I do use them in multiple services (which contain static data at the moment) in order to maintain strongly typed data.

Comment: But does `Coffee` have any instance methods? If not, `ICoffe` is enough to get strong type checking + there will be no need to testing the constructor.

Comment: In principle, you should test the constructor in order to catch behavior change in the future when potentially implementation can change. 100% code coverage is the ultimate (but probably asymptotic) goal.

Comment: @Antoniossss Yes, Coffee is being used.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your input  I'll see what I come up with for the tests.

Comment: I think you didnt understand the question as I never asked if `Coffe` is used or not but if it has any instance methods.....